# Showing which group a customer belongs to in Magento

Tags: magento

I have set up a couple of Customer Groups in Magento (General, Purchase Order Enabled) and i’m wondering if this is easy to display to the customer in their account area so they can see which group they belong to?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe @MagePsycho got it from an old version but on 1.5 you need to change the group model.

```
// Check Customer is loggedin or not
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
      // Get group Id
      $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
      //Get customer Group name
      $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
      echo $group->getCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ovidiu. New code has been tested and works fine for 1.4.x to 1.6.2.0. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code in order to get the group name associated with currently logged in customer:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $groupId    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    $group      = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

    var_dump($group->getCustomerGroupCode());
    //or
    var_dump($group->getCode());
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks