# How can i set different custom login redirect for different types of users?

Tags: php, javascript, magento, jquery

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

In my site i have two types of accounts 1) Normal Buyer Account
                                        2) Seller Account

When the Normal buyer login it should redirect My DashBoard page &
for Seller it should redirect to My Order History page.

for this i tried with this extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-login-redirect.html

but it is working for only one type of user for example  i gave the url for Seller in Normal Buyer account defaultly it showing "You want become a PARTNER Please contact Admin"

How can i solve my task

I am using Magento CE1.7

may be its a duplicate question Sorry just forgive me..

Any ideas ?

Comment: Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own module which basically extends base class `Mage_Customer_AccountController` of Magento and overrides `_loginPostRedirect` function. A complete example can be found here:

[Redirect Customer After Login in Magento](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/11/29/9255/)

Now within that above method of `_loginPostRedirect`, you can get Customer group using following code:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  // Get group Id
  $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
  //Get customer Group name
  $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
  //echo $group->getCode();
  // You got the group code, do the redirection
}
```

Above code for getting customer group is acquired from [Showing which group a customer belongs to in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242390/showing-which-group-a-customer-belongs-to-in-magento)

Comment: Yeah sure Before that remember one thing Boss i'm very new to this technology

Comment: i just tried You mentioned like that only but nothing is happened its as it is only... created a module & controller also

Comment: @Jhon make sure you have created the module correctly (paths,directory structure,XML configuration, naming convention) and also clear all of your cache after creating module. I have posted the very right way and have used this method to override in one my project of CE 1.7 and it was working. Moreover, you need to check error logs to see if there are some `headers already sent` errors! preventing from redirection. See this link for guide on creating module http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: Thanks @Umair Khan its now its working perfectly  But its showing this message for Normal Buyer "FOR BECOME SELLER CONTACT TO ADMIN.."

Comment: @Jhon, good to hear that it's working, can you please mark my reply as answer. Now you need to search for this message in the code i.e. from where it is generating and before that you have to put your `Customer Group` condition, something like `if customer group is Seller: Show this message` `elseif customer group is Buyer: Show that message`.

Comment: Thank you very much for every thing at last i got it